# Maven dependency tree command not working

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

mvn dependency:tree is always trying to download the maven-plugins one by one and it fails at the end. I am not able to see the dependency tree. I have run mvn clean install before running mvn dependency:tree.

`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.9: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.9/maven-dependency-plugin-2.9.pom: Network is unreachable -`

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have added the error message now.

Comment: Ok, so the error message says it's a network problem.

Comment: Apart from the network/firewall/proxy error the given version of that plugin is very old...please check for upgrading the version of the plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/